# React setState callback not called for external (npm packaged) component

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using `setState` with a callback to ensure things run after the state has been updated.

```
...
    this.setState({enabled : true},this.getData);
}
getData () {
    const self = this;
    fetch(this.props.url,{
        method : 'post',
        body : this.state
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function (result) {
        self.update();
    });
}
...
```

`setState` is getting called. `this.state.enabled` does change to `true`. However, `this.getData` is not getting called.

One thing I found interesting is that this is happening for a component I am using via an npm package. In my own code, `setState` with a callback works as designed.

The said external component is also packaged by me. I am using webpack to build it. Might there be something wrong with my webpack config?

Here it is:

```
const Webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index : './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname,'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    library : 'TextField',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  externals : [
    {
      'react' : {
        root : 'React',
        commonjs2 : 'react',
        commonjs : 'react',
        amd : 'react'
      }
    }
  ],
  module: {
      loaders: [
          { test: /\.(js?)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'), query: {cacheDirectory: true, presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2']} }
      ]
  },
  devtool : 'eval'
};
```

Edit:

So now I am pretty sure something fishy is going on when I use my component from a package vs, when I use it from my source.

When I call `setState` from a component which is part of my source-code, this is what is called:

```
ReactComponent.prototype.setState = function (partialState, callback) {
    !(typeof partialState === 'object'
    || typeof partialState === 'function' 
    || partialState == null) ?
        process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 
            invariant(false, 'setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.')
        : _prodInvariant('85')
    : void 0;
    this.updater.enqueueSetState(this, partialState);
    if (callback) {
        this.updater.enqueueCallback(this, callback, 'setState');
    }
};
```

The above is from a file named `ReactBaseClasses.js`

When I call `setState` from a component I packaged as an npm package, this is what is called:

```
Component.prototype.setState = function (partialState, callback) {
    !(typeof partialState === 'object'
      || typeof partialState === 'function'
      || partialState == null) ?
        invariant(false, 'setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.')
        : void 0;
    this.updater.enqueueSetState(this, partialState, callback, 'setState');
};
```

The above is from  a file named `react.development.js`. Notice that callback is passed to `enqueueSetState`. Interestingly, when I break into `enqueueSetState`, the function does nothing with the callback:

```
enqueueSetState: function (publicInstance, partialState) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        ReactInstrumentation.debugTool.onSetState();
        process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? warning(partialState != null, 'setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; ' + 'instead, use forceUpdate().') : void 0;
    }

    var internalInstance = getInternalInstanceReadyForUpdate(publicInstance, 'setState');

    if (!internalInstance) {
        return;
    }

    var queue = internalInstance._pendingStateQueue || 
    (internalInstance._pendingStateQueue = []);
    queue.push(partialState);

    enqueueUpdate(internalInstance);
},
```

Comment: @Li357 this is not a case of the wrong `this`. I have placed a break-point inside the callback, and the break-point itself doesn't get triggered. The callback is not getting called at all. Also, this is a silent failure. I don't get any error messages. It is as if the callback wasn't even specified. (I have also set up a break-point on `setState`, it shows the callback is defined).

Comment: You should post more code in order for readers to help.

Comment: @YangshunTay here's the code for the component: https://github.com/hammadfauz/arrayinput/blob/master/src/index.js (See lines 43 through 54 for the issue)

Comment: can you just show us the full code for the class where you are calling this.setState({enabled : true},this.getData);

Comment: @stack26 `this.setState({enabled : true, this.getData);` was just an example. the real code is at github.com/hammadfauz/arrayinput/blob/master/src/index.js (See lines 43 through 54 for the issue)

Comment: In your component the `handleLookupEnter` never gets called. The callback is working after `setState` fine

Comment: @DivyanshuMaithani `handleLookupEnter` is called via `LookupField`'s `onEnter` prop. I have verified that by placing a breakpoint that hits, inside the `handleLookupEnter` function. What's more, the state changes due to `handleLookupEnter` also happen. Only the callback is not called.

Comment: How does the `onEnter` work here? You should update your question to include these details.

Comment: I think there's a bit more debugging you can do on your end to make the question easier to answer. You mentioned in a comment that you've tried adding an anonymous callback to `setState` instead of supplying `getData` directly (i.e. `setState({ enabled: true }, () => { console.log('called!', this.getData); this.getData(); });`), is that called? If so, what happens when you set a breakpoint in there? You should be able to trace the execution from there. Given the above code, it could be as simple as `this.getData` being undefined, which would explain the behavior, but it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a bug with React. Apparently it was a major bug fix to combine the enqueueSetState and enqueueCallback functionality, but these were separately functioning calls in earlier versions of React.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8577

When importing npm modules, sometimes they bring in different versions of React as dependencies, creating these kinds of inconsistency bugs with setState and callbacks.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10320

Comment: I think NPM should have warned about version inconsistencies when installing my packaged component as `^16` is higher than `^15` which is present. But I might be missing something.

Comment: Yeah... totally agree with that. Is yarn supposedly better at that sort of thing?

Answer (score 1):

You could (and maybe actually should) call the getData method from componentDidUpdate. It will also happen 100% after the state has been changed and (IMHO) will make your code a little less callback hellish.

*Update following comments:*
You can compare your previous state/props with the current ones in componentDidUpdate and then call your method if needed:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps.something !== this.props.something) {
    // do some magic
  }
}
```

Comment: I could. And I have, for some of my components. But that is just a workaround.

In this case, I cannot because the callback is also setting state and results in an update. (I could have a flag to detect whether the update was due to the callback or something else, but that would be exchanging the callback hell for ... 'flag-hell?'

Comment: You can compare the the previous state/props with the current ones and then check do your logic:
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.props.something !== prevProps.something) {
    //  do something else
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

When you set your state, do it like this.

```
this.setState({enabled : true}, () => { this.getData() });
```

The `() => {}` bind `this` to it's lexical parent context.

Comment: Not quite different. How is doing `this.setState({enabled : true}, this.getData);` not giving the same parent context?

Comment: because you are not binding `this` of your `this.getData` to it's right context. Always remember that `this` in javascript is by context

Comment: The `this` in `this.getData` and `() => { this.getData() }` refer to the same thing.

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with the context. I am doing `this.getData = this.getData.bind(this)` in the component's constructor. The callback is not getting called at all.

Comment: That is a valid point @Li357. I have also tried with `this.setState({enabled : true},() => { this.getData() })` But the issue remains. Setting a break-point in the arrow function also does not trigger.

Comment: @YangshunTay Consider this: `function foo(callback) { callback() }`. If I pass `foo(this.myFunc)` it will be called without `this` attached. But if you pass `foo(() => this.myFunc())`, the function will be called with `this` attached and with an arrow function, `this` would resolve to its value in the surrounding scope.

Comment: `this` in javascript is always by context. Although you have binding this.getData.bind(this) in your constructor. But while setting state if you don't use the arrow function notation it won't know which this to bind it with. Because it becomes a nested func. this.setState is a function and inside that function you are calling anther `this` so it's doesn't know which `this` to bind it with. This is why you need to use the arrow func notation.

Comment: exactly what @Li357 said.

Comment: So by your argument, shouldn't `_onSubmit()` alert `undefined` for a click on Button A if they don't have the same `this`? https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/97437/

Comment: @Li357 thanks for the example, you're right. I was confused about the rules for `this` myself. But I'm still surprised the fiddle in my example worked. Unless `setState` binds `this` automatically? Any explanation?

Comment: @YangshunTay It seems so. I checked the source code and I believe React does [indeed call with context](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/1637b43e27c40c73f9489603145f9bb1d0ece618/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberUpdateQueue.js#L352), my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the callback *is* being called successfully from `handleLookupChange`, correct?

So `handleChange` is successfully being called from `handleLookupChange` after the `onEnter` event is triggered and is successfully setting the value for `state`, correct? And that value for `state` is either

`{displayText : self.props.dataSource[selectedIndex]}`

or

`{displayText : newValue}.`

**So here is one possibility.**

I noticed `handleLookupChange` takes two values as arguments from `onEnter` rather than an `event`. It sounds like you said the `onEnter` event successfully delivers the two arguments to `handleLookupChange` and correctly sets `state` based on them. If not my guess would be `handleLookupChange` ought to take the `event` and process it to pass to `handleChange`.

**Or another one.**

If that transition is happening successfully, could this be an issue in how values are received from input after the `onEnter` event?

When you trigger `handleLookupChange` with `onEnter`, is that possible that hitting enter with no text in the input somehow returns newValue not as `null` but as the empty string? This would cause `displayText` to be set as `newValue` (as it is not null), thus causing `displayText` to be set as the empty string, causing the callback `addItem`'s `if` statement never to trigger and run?

Have you checked that `addItem` for sure isn't being called above the `if` statement?

Another thing to check would be whether `dataSource` at `selectedIndex` might be picking up the empty string, which could trigger the `if` statement to not run the inside of `addItem`.

Comment: I guess I would be curious to know how the function passed to onEnter is used within the component and how it passes data to handleLookupChange.

Comment: So, the code is for a component `ArrayInput`, which uses a child component called `LookupField`. Code for `LookupField` is here: https://github.com/hammadfauz/lookupfield/blob/master/src/index.js

LookupField calls its `this.props.onEnter` function when `Enter` key is pressed, and passes it its current value (a string), and an index, which is a number indicating the position of the value in the `LookupField`'s `dataSource` prop.

Comment: Cool, looking it over ... did you confirm that handleLookupChange is being called with the right input and setting state correctly? Also, could you run a console.log before addItem's if statement to see if addItem is being called or whether it's the if statement not being triggered?

Comment: One more question... ArrayInput's this.props.lookup is truthy, so it's for sure rendering the `LookupField` and not the `TextField` component, correct?

Comment: I made an edit to the question with some new findings.

Comment: I wonder if they did actually make the change and it depends on the version of react whether enqueueSetState was changed to handle a callback, vs needing enqueueCallback?

Comment: Oooooh maybe this is the culprit... https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10320 Apparently some npm modules bring in the wrong version of React as dependencies and create this kind of bug.

Comment: I put this in a separate answer to make it more clear, in case someone else comes here looking for an answer to the same problem. (if you think this could be the culprit)

Comment: This could definitely be it! The react version in my component's package.json is `^16.2.0`. The version in my code's package.json is: `^15.6.1`.

Comment: wow, that was genius to think of the npm module thing and look into all those files like that... now you can probably just fix the versioning mismatch and it will work!