# Does React bind this in setState callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I was expecting to see `undefined` being logged when the "Without binding" button was clicked because when you pass a method reference plainly as a callback, it shouldn't be called with the right `this` context, but with an arrow function, it *should*.

However, I saw that the callback function could access `this` and the value of `this.state.number` was logged properly. The method reference and arrow function performed the exact same. Why?

**This does not have to do with arrow function class properties, it has to do with passing a reference to a method as a callback to `setState` as opposed to an arrow function.**

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: 1,
    };
  }

  onClickWithThisBindingInCallback = () => {
    this.setState({ number: 2 }, () => { this.myCallback(); });
  };

  onClickWithoutThisBindingInCallback = () => {
    const myCb = this.myCallback;
    this.setState({ number: 3 }, myCb);
  };

  myCallback() {
    console.log(this.state.number);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.onClickWithThisBindingInCallback}>With binding</button>
        <button onClick={this.onClickWithoutThisBindingInCallback}>Without binding</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React calls the callback function of `setState` with the component's instance `this`, as seen by [this line of code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/1637b43e27c40c73f9489603145f9bb1d0ece618/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberUpdateQueue.js#L352).

Credits: [@Li357](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48134802/react-setstate-callback-not-called-for-external-npm-packaged-component/48134974#comment83247534_48134974)

Comment: I would say it would be best to flag this for community wiki.

Comment: Also, it's not that it *binds* `this`. It just uses the right one when calling `setState`.

Comment: Shocking that [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) doesn't state (and thus guarantee) it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Raised [an issue](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/492).

Answer (score -2):

It is because you are given a lambda function to it:

```
onClickWithThisBinding = () => {
```

A lambda function is executed in it's given context. So the binding is actually `onClick={() => { .. }}`. That is why it has the `this` context.

Answer (score -2):

This is due to the use of the arrow function.

Arrow functions always have the same `this` of their surrounding code.
See more [here](https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-arrows-and-lexical-this).

If you want the method not to be bound to that specific class you can use a normal function like this.

```
onClickWithoutThisBinding() {
    const myCb = this.myCallback;
    this.setState({ number: 3 }, myCb);
};
```

Comment: The point is where how myCallback is being used. The binding of onClickWithoutThisBinding is referring to myCallback not the function itself.

Comment: `this.myCallback` inside the arrow function will be referred to the class `Hello` wherever the `onClickWithoutThisBinding` is called. If you don't use the arrow function instead it will be bound to the class `button` and so will be undefined

Comment: I don't think you understand the issue here. The question is referring to the this of myCallback

Comment: Yes, I got it, but again, as you wrote it, `this.myCallback` is the same in both `onClickWithThisBinding` and `onClickWithoutThisBinding`.
You have to change the scope of the function where `this.myCallback` is being used. If you have a running example I suggest to try it out

Comment: Oh, now I got it, it took me a while